# How can I swap the values of a selective column randomly?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Suppose I have a large data-set(in CSV formate) like the following :

```
   Country  Age  Salary Purchased
0   France   44   72000        No
1    Spain   27   48000       Yes
2  Germany   30   54000        No
3    Spain   38   61000        No
4  Germany   40   45000       Yes
5   France   35   58000       Yes
6    Spain   75   52000        No
7   France   48   79000       Yes
8  Germany   50   83000        No
9   France   37   67000       Yes
```

Now how can i swap all the values for a selected column Randomly ? For Example 
i want to swap all the values of the first column 'Country' randomly.

Looking for your suggestion. Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the meaning of doing so? You'll lose the meaning of your data, won't you?

Comment: @cs95 Sometimes in ML, doing so helps you understand how important a feature is.

Comment: @QuangHoang I get that, but perhaps [there are better ways to do so](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_forest_importances.html).

Comment: @cs95 Feature Importance is one dimension, random shuffle is another. Besides, what do you do if your model is not tree based?

Comment: Anyway, [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) might be what OP's searching for.

Comment: Actually I guess this might help me to find out the dominant factor/feature of the data for a classification problem as brother @QuangHoang said.

Comment: I will try feature importance as @cs95 said. Anymore better idea  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shuffle in-place using `random.shuffle`:

```
# <= 0.23
# np.random.shuffle(df['Country'].values)
# 0.24+
np.random.shuffle(df['Country'].to_numpy())
```

Or, assign back with `random.choice`:

```
df['Country'] = np.random.choice(df['Country'], len(df), replace=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `permutation`

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df.assign(Country=df.Country.to_numpy()[np.random.permutation(len(df))])

   Country  Age  Salary Purchased
0   France   44   72000        No
1  Germany   27   48000       Yes
2   France   30   54000        No
3    Spain   38   61000        No
4   France   40   45000       Yes
5    Spain   35   58000       Yes
6  Germany   75   52000        No
7    Spain   48   79000       Yes
8  Germany   50   83000        No
9   France   37   67000       Yes
```

---

#### `sample`

```
df.assign(Country=df.Country.sample(frac=1).to_numpy())
```